# RecyclerView not calling onCreateViewHolder on activity start

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to implement a simple scrollable list that gets its data from Firebase Database using RecyclerView on an activity called MyOrganisedEventsActivity. Problem is, when my main activity starts the MyOrganisedEventsActivity, there is no call made to the method onCreateViewHolder, and thus the RecyclerView is empty.

However, after waiting a moment and then locking and unlocking my phone, a call is made to onCreateViewHolder and the list items start appearing on the RecyclerView. Is there anyway to force the call when the activity is first started? Or is there something wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Here's my code so far:

MyOrganisedEventsActivity.java:

```
package com.llawl.tristonpang.intheloop;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MyOrganisedEventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OrganisedEventsAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<EventInfo> mEventsDataset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_organised_events);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.org_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        //mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        mEventsDataset = new ArrayList<>();

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new OrganisedEventsAdapter(mEventsDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        prepareEventsData();
    }

    private void prepareEventsData() {
        final String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        Log.d("InTheLoop", "prepareEventsData(), currentUser = " + currentUser);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events_info").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //EventInfo event = snapshot.getValue(EventInfo.class);
                    HashMap<String,String> data = (HashMap) snapshot.getValue();
                    //Log.d("InTheLoop", "Event name: " + event.getName());
                    //if (event.getOrganiser().equals(currentUser)) {
                    if (data.get("organiser").equals(currentUser)) {
                        Log.d("InTheLoop", "Adding event: " + data.get("name"));
                        EventInfo event = new EventInfo(data.get("name"), data.get("date"), data.get("time"), data.get("venue"),
                                data.get("desc"), data.get("imageName"), data.get("organiser"));
                        mEventsDataset.add(event);
                    }



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

OrganisedEventsAdapter.java:

```
package com.llawl.tristonpang.intheloop;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class OrganisedEventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrganisedEventsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<EventInfo> mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mName;
        public TextView mVenue;
        public TextView mDate;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mName = v.findViewById(R.id.org_row_name);
            mVenue = v.findViewById(R.id.org_row_venue);
            mDate = v.findViewById(R.id.org_row_date);
        }
    }

    public OrganisedEventsAdapter(List<EventInfo> dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public OrganisedEventsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.organised_event_row, parent, false);
        Log.d("InTheLoop", "Adapter, onCreateViewHolder");

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        EventInfo event = mDataset.get(position);
        Log.d("InTheLoop", "Adapter, Event name: " + event.getName());
        holder.mName.setText(event.getName());
        holder.mVenue.setText(event.getVenue());
        holder.mDate.setText(event.getDate());
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

EventInfo.java:

```
package com.llawl.tristonpang.intheloop;

public class EventInfo {
    private String mName;
    private String mDate;
    private String mTime;
    private String mVenue;
    private String mDesc;
    private String mImageName;
    private String mOrganiser;

    public EventInfo() {
    }

    public EventInfo(String name, String date, String time, String venue, String desc, String imageName, String organiser) {
        mName = name;
        mDate = date;
        mTime = time;
        mVenue = venue;
        mDesc = desc;
        mImageName = imageName;
        mOrganiser = organiser;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return mTime;
    }

    public String getVenue() {
        return mVenue;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return mDesc;
    }

    public String getImageName() {
        return mImageName;
    }

    public String getOrganiser() {
        return mOrganiser;
    }
}
```

organised_event_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/single_event_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/row_padding_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/org_row_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/org_row_venue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/org_row_name"
        android:text="venue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/org_row_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="date"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_my_organised_events.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyOrganisedEventsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/org_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in wrong place. You should call it when the data in the adapter changes in fact, not when you requested the data from firebase.

Comment: your prepareEventsData(); method is calling after OrganisedEventsAdapter (constructor) is called.

so your mEventsDataset object is null and you send that object into constructor.
it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` . You have missed the nature of asynchronous call.

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events_info").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // Build data here
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you add data in `List` in `for loop` in `onDataChange()`

so basically add data in your data structure and then notify adapter to update itself with new data.